# Fatal error: can't find pdcurses.dll for linking, make sure PDCurses v3.4+ is in the same folder as UniCurses

Tags: python-3.x, module, curses, pdcurses, unicurses

1. I've imported curses in python but then when I tried to run the program from cmd it said **ModuleNotFoundError: no module named '_curses'**.
2. I searched for Unicurses for my version of Python then installed it, 
   then I did the same with PDcurses and I've put the content of the zip file on my python folder.
3. I used IDLE and typed import unicurses and got the error:
   **Fatal error: can't find pdcurses.dll for linking, make sure PDCurses v3.4+ is in the same folder as UniCurses if you want to use UniCurses on a win32 platform.
   Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\unicurses.py", line 43, in 
    import curses   # see if the platform supports curses natively
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 13, in 
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'**
```

In fact I didn't find any pdcurses.dll, but it wasn't even placed in the file that I downloaded.

I installed Unicurses from the basic installer like everyone and then transefered the pdcurses downloaded content in the main python folder.
I'm on windows 7.
EDIT: Installed curses with pip using pip install windows-curses command
but now I get a black screen when trying to run on cmd